# How to distinguish between 2 or more entry fields in code

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Raw newbie to Xamarin here. VS 2019, C#, latest Xamarin.
Looked everywhere but must be searching with non-relevant search terms.

So if I have 2 or more entry fields on a Xamarin form how do I know which one caused an event like onCompleted to fire. I do not see a Name or Id property for an entry field.

Comment: Did you find "x:Name" ?

Comment: Know nothing about "x:Name" and will search. But in the meantime would you be kind enough to show its use in xaml and OnEntryTextChanged.

Comment: Hi! If at the end you finally found a way to solve your problem please share it, or if the answer published below helped to achieve your goal, mark it as answer. By doing so you make this post useful for others having a similar issue. Thanks for contributing to the SO community!

Answer (score 0):

**[Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.entry?view=xamarin-forms)** (and `Element` in general!) have an [`Id` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.id?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Element_Id) that can be retrieved when you need it, to uniquely identify them.

If you have an `Entry myEntry`, then you can identify it on your event handler as:

```
Entry myEntry = new Entry()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid()
};

...

void Entry_Completed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var entryID = ((Entry)sender).Id; //cast sender to access the properties of the Entry
    if (entryID.ToString() == myEntry.Id.ToString())
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

I hope that helps!

**Note: Not proved code!**

Comment: Thanks Julipan for taking the time to answer but I'm not sure how this relates to my question or maybe too advanced for me. "x:Name" seems to be what I was looking for as the name that is declared in XAML can be easily accessed in the code-behind.

Comment: @notIntoXS, well if x:Name is enough for your purpose, then good for you. The id i talk about would let you to uniquely identify an Entry, say if you set the same event handler to a set of entries. I would be curious to know, with x:Name how could you tell which Entry fired the event... which is what you asked for in your original post. If at the end you solve your problem please let us know how was your final solution, that could help others.

Comment: Thanks Julipan. If just one event handler for multiple fields is the the objective then indeed your solution is probably the best. I wasn't intending to explicitly require only 1 event handler.